# python write pyspark dataframe to json without header

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My apologies for the similar question asked previously. This question is in Python. But I can't find correct solution I have the following dataframe df1

```
SomeJson
=================
[{
         "Number": "1234",
         "Color": "blue",
         "size": "Medium"
     }, {
         "Number": "2222",
         "Color": "red",
         "size": "Small"
     }
]
```

and I am trying to write just the contents of this dataframe as a json.

```
df0.coalesce(300).write.mode('append').json(<json_Path>)
```

It brings in the first key as well like:

```
{
        "SomeJson": [{
                "Number": "1234",
                "Color": "blue",
                "size": "Medium"
            }, {
                "Number": "2222",
                "Color": "red",
                "size": "Small"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**but, I would not like to have  { "SomeJson": } this in the output file. I have tried to write below. But, I am getting lost at writing the custom Python function to eliminate the first header. Any assistance is highly appreciated**

```
df0.rdd.map(<custom_function>).saveAsTextFile(<json_Path>)
```

Comment: JSON by default doesn't have headers, as column information is inside the object.  do `your_df.printSchema()` and post it to the question

Comment: You can try this : `import json
df0.rdd.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x["SomeJson"])).saveAsTextFile("filepath")`

Comment: Hi user238607,  thanks for your efforts.  am only getting values of each key in square brackets like ["1234" ,"blue"]. But, I would like to have along with keys in json format but not the first key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer : [Convert pyspark dataframe into list of python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059995/convert-pyspark-dataframe-into-list-of-python-dictionaries)

You can do something like this:

```
df0.rdd.map(lambda x: [ele.asDict() for ele in x["SomeJson"]]).saveAsTextFile("data/output.json")
```

It produces output like this :

```
[{'Color': 'blue', 'Number': '1234', 'size': 'Medium'}, {'Color': 'red', 'Number': '2222', 'size': 'Small'}]
```

**Edit:**

Spark doesn't maintain the order when the json is being read. But we can change the order of the dictionary we receive. Since dictionary in python3 maintains insertion order, we just need to create a new dictionary considering the order into account. Rest of the stuff is just string manipulation. Here's how I would do it.

```
required_order = ["Number","Color","size"]

def change_order(row_dict, order):
    temp_dict = {}
    for name in order:
        temp_dict[name] = row_dict[name]
    return temp_dict

df0.rdd.map(lambda x: "{" + ",".join([str(ele) for ele in [change_order(ele.asDict(), required_order) for ele in x["SomeJson"]]]) + "}").saveAsTextFile("data/output.json")
```

It produces the following output.

```
{{'Number': '1234', 'Color': 'blue', 'size': 'Medium'},{'Number': '2222', 'Color': 'red', 'size': 'Small'}}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way for enclosing the whole in curly braces and not the square brackets. Also, not changing the order of elements by keeping original order as is

Comment: This Looks perfect. thanks. you may close this. just in case if any of the future persons reviewing the answer, it will be highly appreciated if the logic just eliminates the key and doesn't change anything