# Convert pyspark dataframe into list of python dictionaries

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I'm new to pyspark and I'm trying to convert pyspark.sql.dataframe into list of dictionaries.

Below is my dataframe, the type is <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>:

```
+------------------+----------+------------------------+
|             title|imdb_score|Worldwide_Gross(dollars)|
+------------------+----------+------------------------+
| The Eight Hundred|       7.2|               460699653|
| Bad Boys for Life|       6.6|               426505244|
|             Tenet|       7.8|               334000000|
|Sonic the Hedgehog|       6.5|               308439401|
|          Dolittle|       5.6|               245229088|
+------------------+----------+------------------------+
```

I would like to convert it into:

```
[{"title":"The Eight Hundred", "imdb_score":7.2, "Worldwide_Gross(dollars)":460699653},
 {"title":"Bad Boys for Life", "imdb_score":6.6, "Worldwide_Gross(dollars)":426505244},
 {"title":"Tenet", "imdb_score":7.8, "Worldwide_Gross(dollars)":334000000},
 {"title":"Sonic the Hedgehog", "imdb_score":6.5, "Worldwide_Gross(dollars)":308439401},
 {"title":"Dolittle", "imdb_score":5.6, "Worldwide_Gross(dollars)":245229088}]
```

How should I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can map each row into a dictionary and collect the results:

`df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()`